# Cannot POST data into the database

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest

I'm trying to add some data (strings) from my android app using POST. I'm currently testing the code with the Advanced Rest Client however so the imput's from there.

EDIT: To make it more clear what my question is - what's wrong with the code that it doesn't take the values and assign them? why does it skip the first if?

EDIT 2: I am using chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/… to test this POST.

NOTES:

echo @name;  -> it does nothing, doesn't echo a thing

Right now, it automatically enters the third else saying that required field(s) are missing.

I've tried using var_dump on $name and it states the following: Unexpected token s   => that didn't make any sense.

Thanks in advance for the answers, if you need more info I'll gladly provide it.

This is the code:

```
$app->post('/users', function() use ($app, $mysql) {
    $name = $app->request->post('name');
    $email = $app->request->post('email');
    $beer_type = $app->request->post('beer_type');
    $favorite_beer = $app->request->post('favorite_beer');
    $favorite_drink = $app->request->post('favorite_drink');

    echo $name;

 if (!empty($name) and !empty($email) and !empty($beer_type) and !empty($favorite_beer) and !empty($favorite_drink)) {

 $insert = "INSERT INTO clients(name, email) VALUES({$name}, {$email})";
 $getid = "SELECT id_client FROM clients WHERE email = {$email}";
 $insert2 = "INSERT INTO preferences(client_id, beer_type, favorite_beer, favorite_drink) VALUES({$idvalue}, {$beer_type}, {$favorite_beer}, {$favorite_drink})";

$request = $mysql->query($insert);
$test = false;
$id = 0;
$test2 = false;
if ($request !== false) {
    $test = true;
}
if ($test === true) {
    $request = $mysql->query($getid);
    if ($request !== false) {
        $id = $request->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
}
if ($id !== 0) {
    $request = $mysql->query($insert2);
    if ($request !== false) {
        $test2 = true;
    }
}

if ($test2 === true) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 }else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

 });
```

Comment: Apparently your POST code is no good.

Comment: You'll need to provide the code that actually performs the POST

Comment: @dave.c As I stated in my question details, I am using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo  to test this POST. I've added the following test code with it: Random Name, random@yahoo.com, draft, Kwak, Green Apple for the 5 values that need added. If you need my android code as well, i can provide it, but I haven't proofed it yet as there's no point if the POST doesn't work from the advanced rest client. All other links work perfectly fine in it except this one. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by changing the java code. I used the [Ion Library](https://github.com/koush/ion) for the POST and it worked perfectly fine.